# Read requests and responses made by browser on naviagating a web page in C# webdriver

Tags: selenium2, webdriver, browser-automation, c#

I wants to read all the requests and responses made and get by the browser on navigating on a page.

*For example:* If I navigate to http://www.yahoo.com then we observe that browser is making a lots of GET and post requests. For the purpose of image loading, content loading and to display the Ads (Advertisement).

I am using selenium web driver and C#.

Can you please help me how can I get all the requests (get/post) and responses?

Comment: Why web driver, shouldn't you be using a network tool like Fiddler or Wireshark ?

Comment: HI Phil.......thanks ......I got my answer........... 

The best way to accomplish this is to use some sort of scriptable proxy. One such proxy is the BrowserMob proxy, and there's even a .NET wrapper for it. This would allow you to gather information that is outside the scope of WebDriver, such as the raw HTTP requests that you are asking for. ........I got this answer from one of friend on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I haven't used it, but possible it may be helpfull for you:

[FiddlerCore](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler/Core/)

And one more alternative:
[BrowserMob Proxy](http://www.adathedev.co.uk/2012/02/automating-web-performance-stats.html)

Comment: Thanks Dmitry.I used BrowserMob Proxy and its working fine. These people are very helpful.